# Create a repository using a template in GitHub

Tags: github, repository

I am trying to create a repository by following [this](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#create-a-repository-using-a-template) page, but it gives the following message after running curl:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-using-a-template"
}
```

Here is the command I tried:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: token <my-token>" https://api.github.com/repos/TEMPLATE_OWNER/TEMPLATE_REPO/generate -d '{"owner":"<my-username>","name":"<my-repo-name>","description":"Demo desc":false,"private":true}'
```

I also tried to replace `TEMPLATE_OWNER` with my username and `TEMPLATE_REPO` with my repo name, but still the same error.

So, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

did you set the repo is_template key to true?

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#create-a-repository-using-a-template

> To check if a repository is available to use as a template, get the repository's information using the Get a repository endpoint and check that the is_template key is true.

Comment: But I will create an inexisted repo, for this reason which repo should I look at to check is_template key?

Comment: that api create a repo (non-existed repo) from a template (an exist repo that enabled is_template). you should enable it at the template repo

Comment: Ok, but where is template repo? Could you explain a little bit more for me who is beginner on GitHub :)